# Placing div on captured coordinates going outside the page

Tags: javascript, html, coordinates

I have a Main div inside which i am trying to display another small div on the coordinates captured on mouse click. Problem is that when i click on the extreme left, right, top, bottom the small div is going outside the main div. I have tried `overflow:hidden` on main div but i don't want that. i want div to be positioned inside the main div no matter where i click.
Sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main_div").bind('click', function(event){

    var x = event.pageX-document.getElementById("main_div").scrollLeft;
    var y = event.pageY-document.getElementById("main_div").scrollTop;



    $("#container-5").css({"top":y,"left":x});
   });
```

Comment: [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNkQU/) for you.  Is this the type of behavior you're seeing?  What exactly would you like to happen when the small div gets near the edge?  Should it shrink, should it stop moving, or should part of it become hidden?

Comment: When the small div comes near the edge of the main div it should be pulled back into the div. I want the div to be inside the main div completely when i click on edge. i have tried to set the top left position of small div but it will help me only when i try to place it on left edge of the main div.

Comment: Seeing your code. Check when u click on left side of main div. Small div is completely inside the main div. Similarly i want that too happen when i click on right, bottom or top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the coordinates of the click would put part of the small div outside of the main div, and if so change the coordinates so that the small div remains inside the main div.  (See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNkQU/3/).)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main_div").bind('click', function(event) {
        var $mainDiv = $("#main_div");
        var $container5 = $("#container-5");

        var x = event.pageX - $mainDiv.position().left;
        var y = event.pageY - $mainDiv.position().top;

        if (x + $container5.width() > $mainDiv.width()) {
            x = $mainDiv.width() - $container5.width();
        }
        if (y + $container5.height() > $mainDiv.height()) {
            y = $mainDiv.height() - $container5.height();
        }

        $container5.css({
            "top": y,
            "left": x
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am dynamically trying to create div and i am saving the id as `var dividforcanvas=document.getElementById("image"+i);` then later when i go inside the if loop. It catches an exception saying `dividforcanvas.width` is not a function. Please help

Comment: Are you sure than an element with id `"image"+i` exists?  Can I see the code that dynamically creates it?